# King of Mithila after Janaka

Tags: ramayana, janaka

Who became king of Mithila after Raja Janaka (Sita's father) passed away? Did Sri Rama inherit that being Janaka's son in law?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janaka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vishnu Purana gives the descendants lists.

- Actually there were two Janaka in the dynasty of Mithila.
- One was the first King, made by the Sages, then was the one whom we popularly call as Janaka, the father of goddess Sītā, actual name being Sīradhwaja

> [Chapter V](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vishnu-purana-wilson/d/doc116001.html), Book 4, Vishnu Purana
>
> **As Nimi left no successor, the Munis, apprehensive of the
> consequences of the earth being without a ruler, agitated the body of
> the prince, and produced from it a prince who was called Janaka, from
> being born without a progenitor**. In consequence of his father being
> without a body (videha), he was termed also Vaideha, ‘the son of the
> bodiless;’ and the further received the name of Mithi, from having
> been produced by agitation (mathana). **The son of Janaka was
> Udāvasu; his son was Nandivarddhana; his son was Suketu;** his son was
> Devarāta; his son was Vrihaduktha; his son was Mahāvīrya; his son was
> Satyadhriti; his son was Dhṛṣṭaketu; his son was Haryyaśva; his son
> was Maru; his son was Pratibandhaka; his son was Kritaratha; his son
> was Krita; his son was Vibudha; his son was Mahādhriti; his son was
> Kritirāta; his son was Mahāroman; his son was Suvarṇaroman; his son
> was Hraswaroman; his son was Sīradhwaja (the Second Janaka).
>
> **Sīradhwaja ploughing the ground, to prepare it for a sacrifice which
> he instituted in order to obtain progeny, there sprang up in the
> furrow a damsel, who became his daughter Sītā**.
>
> **The brother of
> Sīradhwaja was Kuśadhwaja, who was king of Kāśī; he had a son also,
> named Bhānumat. The son of Bhānumat was Satadyumna; his son was
> Śuci;** his son was Ūrjjavāha; his son was Śatyadhwaja; his son was
> Kuni; his son was Añjana; his son was Ritujit; his son was
> Aṛṣṭanemi; his son was Śrutāyus; his son was Supārśva; his son was
> Sañjaya; his son was Kṣemāri; his son was Anenas; his son
> was Mīnaratha; his son was Satyaratha; his son was Sātyarathi;
> his son was Upagu; his son was Śruta; his son was Sāswata;
> his son was Sudhanwan; his son was Subhāsa; his son was Suśruta;
> his son was Jaya; his son was Vijaya; his son was Rita; his son was
> Sunaya; **his son was Vītahavya; his son was Dhriti; his son was
> Bahulāśva; his son was Kriti, with whom terminated the family of
> Janaka.** These are the kings of Mithilā, who for the most part will
> be proficient in spiritual knowledge.
>
> English Translation by H.H. Wilson

<sup>Access the (Sanskrit + Hindi) Translation of the same by Gita Press Gorakhpur [from here](https://archive.org/details/vishnu-puran-illustrated-with-hindi-translations-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n268/mode/1up?view=theater)</sup>

### To conclude:

- There were several descendants after the first king of Mithila who was also called Janaka, first being his son Udāvasu, then his grandson Suketu.
- After the second Janaka (father of goddess Sītā), his nephew - Bhānumat, the son of King of Kashi (Janaka's brother - Kuśadhwaja) succeeded the kingdom of Mithila, which ultimately terminated in king Kriti, the son of Bahulāśva.